# Program Reasoning, python function

Tags: python

Program reasoning requires us to find the input for the function so that it outputs a certain result.
The function is:

```
def func1(stuff, more_stuff=None):
    data = []
    for i, thing in enumerate(stuff):
        if thing >= 0 or i < 2:
            data.append(thing + i)
    print(len(stuff))
    if more_stuff is not None:
        data += more_stuff
    print(data)
```

And the expected output is:

```
4
[5, 3, 1, 5, -3]
```

The closest I can get it is:

```
4
[5, 3, 2, 5, -3]
```

with func1([5,2,0,2], [-3]) as input

I'm having trouble trying to get the the 1 and I'm just wanting to know how/why you can get a 1 as if it's anything less than 0 ie -1 as value for that index then 'thing' is < 0 and i = 2  so it skips that value/index and the output will be:

```
4
[5, 3, 5, -3]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is the length of `stuff` must be 4, NOT the length of `data` after the first for loop. You're absolutely right that you run into the problem where data[2] can never be 1 if you are trying to use `stuff` to fill `data`.

To fix this issue, chop `stuff` off before that and use `more_stuff` to append the values you need.

Ie the input you're looking for is:

```
>>>func1([5, 2, -1, -1], [1, 5, -3])
4
[5, 3, 1, 5, -3]
```